# ImageView - Out of memory?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Im storing a couple of images and videos all in my raw folder.

The vidoes plays fine, but once I want to show an image I get this :

Even if the image starts first before the videos it happesn

```
package com.example.tvrplayer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {

    int playListIndex;
    int currentMedia;
    String mediaName;
    ArrayList<Integer> playList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private VideoView videoView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Uri mediaPath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        createPlayList();
        currentMedia = 1;
        try {
            playMedia(this, currentMedia);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
//      play next video
        currentMedia++;
        if (currentMedia > playList.size() - 1) {
            currentMedia = 0;
        }
        try {
            playMedia(this, currentMedia);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void playMedia(Context context, int playListIndex) throws IOException {
        int resourceID = playList.get(playListIndex); // This is the resource id
        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + resourceID;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        String filename = context.getResources().getResourceName(resourceID);
        if (filename.contains("image")) {
            imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(resourceID);
        } else if (filename.contains("video")) {
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.start();
        }
    }

    private void createPlayList() {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
        for(java.lang.reflect.Field f : fields)
        try {
            playList.add(f.getInt(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { }      

        java.lang.reflect.Field[] imagefields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
        for(java.lang.reflect.Field f : imagefields)
        try {
            playList.add(f.getInt(null));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { }  
    }

}
```

This is what comes up in the console:

```
02-19 15:56:01.095: E/AlarmManagerService(190): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 614361.925000000
02-19 15:56:02.962: E/AlarmManagerService(190): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=0, 1361290750.991000000
02-19 15:56:03.111: D/dalvikvm(931): GC_CONCURRENT freed 719K, 13% free 7177K/8199K, paused 5ms+2ms
02-19 15:56:03.705: D/dalvikvm(931): GC_CONCURRENT freed 31K, 9% free 7532K/8199K, paused 4ms+1ms
02-19 15:56:03.892: D/Finsky(931): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
02-19 15:56:11.642: E/Watchdog(190): !@Sync 6562
02-19 15:56:12.377: E/AlarmManagerService(190): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 614812.728000000
02-19 15:56:12.384: I/GTalkService/c(451): [AndroidEndpoint@1093714392] connect: acct=1000001, state=CONNECTING
02-19 15:56:12.556: E/GTalkService(451): connectionClosed: no XMPPConnection - That's strange!
02-19 15:56:12.564: E/AlarmManagerService(190): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 614614.495000000
02-19 15:56:15.572: D/ConnectivityService(190): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=1, condition=0, published condition=0
02-19 15:56:15.572: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(272): onReceive() - CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, INET_CONDITION_ACTION
02-19 15:56:15.572: D/STATUSBAR-NotificationService(190): cancelNotification - pkg:com.android.systemui, id:273, tag:null
02-19 15:56:41.642: E/Watchdog(190): !@Sync 6563
02-19 15:56:59.994: E/AlarmManagerService(190): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 614363.041000000
02-19 15:57:00.002: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(190): received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
02-19 15:57:00.009: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(190): handleTimeUpdate
02-19 15:57:00.009: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(272): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
02-19 15:57:00.009: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(272): updateClock :15:57
02-19 15:57:00.033: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(272): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
02-19 15:57:00.033: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(272): updateClock :15:57
02-19 15:57:01.111: E/AlarmManagerService(190): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=3, 614421.926000000
02-19 15:57:11.642: E/Watchdog(190): !@Sync 6564
```

I need to play the images form the raw folder, not the drawable for the purpous of this app. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Nothing is wrong with Garbage Collection. If it happens continuously for a long time, you have a memory leak. But if your app is out of memory, you will receive an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Comment: This image is should display as soon as the app starts. so nothing else is happening before this

Comment: How much is your image size (pixel and ko), OOM means you fill up too much the stack. Also the LogCat doesn't talk about your problem :o

Comment: I added the image information to the question